# How change architecture and compiler PHP?

Tags: php, windows

I'm on windows server 2022.
I have not seen any questions on how change "Architecture" for PHP?
Also how to change compiler Visual C++ 2017 to C++ 2019?

TIA.

[image]
[image]

I installed Visual Studio 2022.
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your desired php here [PHP downloads archive](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/)
Download the proper version and install it on your machine.

Changing the compiler is not probably something you can do easily, the newer PHP versions have been built using newer C++ compilers indeed.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)